# Shopify: Where does the styles in notification emails come from?

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

I [asked this in Shopify](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-discussion/t/where-do-the-css-rules-in-notification-emails-come-from-500491) forum but no one answers.

In Shopify's admin page, we can edit the HTML of "order confirmation" email, when I get the actual email, the HTML is very different from the one we edit in the admin's page, though I can tell it comes from the same HTML that I edit on admin page. It's just that many styles are added and some HTML elements' order seems changed. I am wondering how these styles are added? Do we have control over it?

This is what I see in gmail as of the order confirmation email:
[image]

As you can see the `<p>` tag has many styles. However, on admin's page, the related code is:

```
{% capture email_body %}
  {% if requires_shipping %}
    Hi {{ customer.first_name }}, we're getting your order ready to be shipped. We will notify you when it has been sent.
  {% endif %}
{% endcapture %}

.....

<p>{{ email_body }}</p>
```

There is no styles at all and there is no CSS regarding this P tag.

Comment: Not just the styles, but the placeholder for the date is also missing from the text in the template. Are you absolutely sure this is the template used?

Answer (score 1):

Shopify loads default styles.css file in all email templates.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/notifications/styles.css">
```

Before sending email, Shopify parses all that external CSS and add them as inline styles to better support different email clients.

More information on [Shopify Website](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/sell-online/notifications/edit-template)